# Why do browsers have their own codecs, instead of supporting all ones already present in operating system?

Tags: html5-video, codec

I mean all the video applications support any codec you have already installed in your operating system. Why do browsers have to behave differently in their  tag and not supports those codecs already present in OS?

I think browsers can have native support for some codecs (which they wish to work everywhere), but can supports also the ones from OS. Don't they? If so, why?
Thanks

I was just checking source code of Google Chrome (or I should rather say Chromium), and it uses FFmpeg library to play video. The same library which is used by almost all video apps on linux and which can play figuratively all the video formats out there. So it seems it would be easy to support **any** codec, but Google enumerated only some of them: see function `VideoCodecToCodecID` in http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/media/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_common.cc

Comment: Maybe you're confused between "codec" and "plugin" (software module that allows a browser to play media)?  This is not really a programming question.

Comment: So would it be fair to say that the question is, really, why doesn't a given media plugin support the same set of codecs like a media player application.

Comment: I mean support in <video> tag, which is native in browsers (not a plugin). Isn't it? I'm developing a video based web app and this makes a problem, that most of user's videos are not playable by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Because different operating systems support completely different codecs, which requires browsers to provide their own implementations.

As an example, consider Windows XP.  It has horrible codec support.  Basically, it supported WMV9/VC-1 and a splattering of shitty codecs nobody cares about.  It didn't support MPEG2, MPEG4, H.264, etc, which explains why millions of us couldn't figure out how the hell to get it to play a DVD.  And the reason for this is MSFT didn't want to pay royalties; some bean-counter clearly thought it more wise to throw money developing a proprietary codec (hence VC-1) than bother paying royalties to MPEG-LA.  I'm sure the math made sense, but beyond that it was moronic.

Contrast that with OSX: Apple licensed MPEG2 (and later H.264) to make it easier for their customers to playback this video content.  It cost them money, but nobody went nuts trying to figure out how to playback a DVD.

So that leaves us with FireFox: if they allowed the underlying OS to dictate what codecs were supported, then they'd be left with dramatically different support depending on what platform the browser was installed on.  And that's just sort of a crappy user experience.  So most browsers have taken to shipping with some basic codec support built-in.

Unfortunately, that sucks.  Because browsers can't seem to decide if they're going to support H.264 or WebM, which leave programmers up shit creek without a paddle.  Oh well.  Some things never change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with some encoding algorithms being patented and requiring browser makers to pay royalties to use them.

The reason why you can use all your system's codecs in your old-fashioned <embed Windows Media Player> HTML tag is because you're loading an ActiveX component from Windows Media Player that can use all the codecs. The browser maker (Mozilla, Google) does not pay any royalties as they can ambed any ActiveX, not just WMP.

Moreover, there are obnoxious  companies like Apple who does not support royalty-free format X, Y, Z because they don't want to change their existing codebase.

The 3 main formats for HTML5 are Ogg, H.264 and WebM. Unfortunately, there's no one format that works on all major browsers (MSIE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) so the solution is:

- produce video in all three formats
- use the HTML5 video's `<source>` element to input all three in the hTML5 element
- let the browser decide which one to use. This happens automatically.

Here is an example:

```
<video id="intro">
    <source src="intro.ogm" />
    <source src="intro.webm" />
    <source src="intro.mkv" />
</video>
```

If exporting your video to these formats is not possible I believe you should stick to ol' good Flash :P.

Comment: I think it would be possible for browsers to ship with just some basic codecs to avid patent problems, but then relaying on the operating system for the rest. I.e. the patented codecs would be in your system already, the question how they got there is irrelevant now (perhaps with another app or video player you paid for).

Comment: As I just added to my original question, Google Chrome uses a library which support all these codecs, but Chrome whitelists just some of them :( This looks like they have the codecs there, but disabled.